# TLC59116F (i2c led driver) everything seems ok but LED doesn't work

Tags: arduino, led, pwm, i2c

I'm trying the LED driver [TLC59116F](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc59116f) with an arduino UNO R3. This IC is a i2c controllable LED driver with PWM and 16 outputs. The registers seem all loaded fine, here's a print of their contents:

```
0:11
1:0
2:C8
3:C8
4:C8
5:C8
6:C8
7:C8
8:C8
9:C8
A:C8
B:C8
C:C8
D:C8
E:C8
F:C8
10:C8
11:C8
12:FF
13:FF
14:FF
15:FF
16:FF
17:FF
18:D2
19:D4
1A:D8
1B:D0
```

As you can see, all outputs are on C8 (200) which should be high brightness.. and all LED are active I think (the FF registers). I have attached an LED to OUT0 like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpILUw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I attach the led to GND instead of OUT0 it (of course) works fine. The IC talks fine on i2c therefore it shouldn't be burnt.. The IC power comes directly from the arduino 5v, which is in turn powered by the USB connection.

Comment: So what is the question, please?

Comment: V1 = 1V? I hope that's just an error in the diagram.

Comment: image was wrong, it's 5V

Answer (score 2):

The problem was actually very easy, I missed in the datasheet that you need to have a resistor Rext connected to pin 1 - GND, and this resistor defines the maximum output current. Without it no current is outputted, ever.